# django won't load staticfiles from statifiles_dirs

Tags: python, css, django, styles, django-staticfiles

My `style.css` is placed in `appname/static/appname/`.

My `settings.py` has this code:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/"),
    )
```

And in my `base.html` I load it like this:

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'appname/style.css' %}">
```

But the styles are not loading. 
If I remove `STATICFILES_DIRS` and change `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` to `STATIC_URL = '/static/appname/'`, it works perfectly, but I guess it's not the best practice for the case I'll add any other app to the project later. What I might be doing wrong?

Comment: This should work, I mean your configuration. The line `STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/"),)` means that django will search in the directory `rootproject/static/`, not in your apps `static` . What is your directory structure?

Answer (score 1):

Just change one thing,

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
```

It will search in static folder inside your app. Also if you want to add a specific directory,

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"), '/your specific directory/',
)
```

From here you can directly add the particular file name, and djnago will search in that specific directory.

Comment: _"Your project will probably also have static assets that aren’t tied to a **particular app**. In addition to using a static/ directory inside your apps, you can define a list of directories (STATICFILES_DIRS) in your settings file where Django will also look for static files"_. This is only needed if you want an extra directory besides the apps.

Answer (score 0):

Remove "appname" in {% static 'appname/style.css' %}, you must not place it there because python knows automatically in which application the file is, it get the application name from the request

Comment: You should see the HTTP call in the django terminal, seek the relative to syle.css and copy it here

Comment: is says "GET /static/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1651, seems like it doesnt check STATICFILES_DIRS...?

Comment: ad using the appname?

Comment: Then it doesn't say anything regarding styles.css

Comment: System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
September 19, 2018 - 13:34:26
Django version 2.1.1, using settings 'md5light.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[19/Sep/2018 13:34:34] "GET /appname/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1443

Comment: you don't see any HTTP call for style.css?

Comment: The thing is, I have two apps in this project, both have the same structure and the same code for loading static, and for one styles work with STATIC_URL='/static/' and for another it doesnt.

Comment: well ok, now i noticed it just applies old styles to anoher app, now i changed 'styles.css' for the second app but i looks just the same as it was (i changed a {color: green} to a { color: red;} and the links are still green)...

Comment: look: i just removed STATICFILES_DIRS from settings.py and changed STATIC_URL to '/static/appname/' and now styles are applied to both appname and appname2. Same happens if i make STATIC_URL='/static/appname2/'. why is that happening?

Comment: Though with STATIC_URL='/static/appname2/' if I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/appname2/ it says "GET /static/getmd5/getmd5/style.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0 in console.

Answer (score 0):

By default django picks `static` directory from app's directory. So, if your static directory is inside app directory there is no need to specify `STATICFILES_DIRS`. 
Now `/static/` will point to files and directories in the static directory of your app. To refer your css file use

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'appname/style.css' %}">
```

Comment: make sure `STATICFILES_DIRS = []`