# Django problem with loading CSS and/or JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, django-staticfiles

[image: PROJECT-BASE.HTML]

Hello, I've got a project to do and I've been wanting to implement CSS and JS to my Django project WITHOUT using Bootstrap. And as you can see I have personal_portfolio/static/css/navbar.css
But when I load static files and use the  tag inside my base.html the page doesn't apply my stylesheet. I do not understand why !  [image: website image showing the CSS is not working]
Whereas when I use bootstrap I have no problem ! 
I've been wanting to use only CSS and JS cause I want to learn those as well and the project I have requires me to do it myself and not use Bootstrap.
[image: here's a part of my css]
Thanks a lot, I hope you all can help me !

Comment: in settings.py set `static_url` and `staticfiles_dir` - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATIC_URL

Comment: I already set it but it doesn't seem to work. It still asks me for STATIC_ROOT
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
 I tried looking at the documentation but I do not understand anything

Comment: `personal_portfolio` is app or project name ?... you have configured your settings as your static files are under root folder, so be sure it should be under your root project only.

Comment: If you are under development - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

Comment: PERSONAL_PORTFOLIO is my project name. PROJECTS is my app name. I tried putting my personal_portfolio/static/css/navbar.css as rp-portfolio/static/css/navbar.css so it's in the ROOT but it still doesn't work.

Comment: PERSONAL_PORTFOLIO is root don't change it to `rp-portfolio/static/css/navbar.css `. In console what is the path of that file ?

Comment: /Django/rp-portfolio/personal_portfolio/static/css/navbar.css.  @PankajSharma are you able to go on discord if you have time so you can help me ?

Comment: put static files on same dir as your `manage.py` file is and `BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))`, `STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),]`

Comment: FINALLY - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

Comment: my BASE_DIR, STATIC_URL and STATICFILES_DIRS is already set up this way. I went through the documentation you sent and I tried what they said but it still doesn't work ? It doesn't show me any error but it just doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using
`{% load static %}`
instead of `{% load staticfiles %}`

Comment: Tried, still doesn't work. I really don't understand why bootstrap works so easily but not css files

Comment: How are you loading bootstrap? If it is using a CDN then your issue comes from your configuration. Make sure you set `STATIC_URL ='/static/'` and `STATICFILES_DIRS = [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'personal_portfolio/static')`,

Comment: Hi, STATICFILES_DIRS = (
     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static/'),
     'personal_portfolio/static/') I used this and it worked but I don't understand what the os.path.join(BASE_DIR does ? I mean by this why don't I have to put os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'personal_portfolio/static') ????

Comment: I found the same answer ! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52403518/django-wont-load-staticfiles-from-statifiles-dirs I just needed to add a different dir !

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this will solve your problem but try running
`python manage.py collectstatic`
from your terminal before running the django server.

Comment: It Tells me this :  File "/Users/gabe/Desktop/Gabe/Programming/Django/rp-portfolio/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 44, in path
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("You're using the staticfiles app "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path. This is only the end of the Traceback error